# Combinations and Permutations: John is to select a committee of 4 individuals from among a group of 5 candi­dates

Tags: combinatorics

> John is to select a committee of 4 individuals from among a group of 5
> candi­dates. The committee will have a President, a Vice President,
> and two Trea­surers. How many different committees can John select
> from the 5 candidates?

Hi, I'm having a very hard time understanding the logic of Combinations and Permutations so I hope someone could help me out.

I have 2 answers for this questions and I don't know which one is correct:

So there are

5 people: A, B, C, D, E, F

4 positions: P (President), V (Vice President), T (Trea­surer), X (Not chosen)

**First answer:**

> A takes 1 out of 5 positions: 5 ways (For example A takes T)
>
> B takes 1 out of 4 positions: 4 ways (For example B takes V)
>
> C takes 1 out of 3 positions: 3 ways (For example C takes P)
>
> D takes 1 out of 2 positions: 2 ways (For example D takes X)
>
> E takes 1 out of 1 positions: 1 way (For example E takes T)
>
> So it is 5! ways
>
> Then there are 5! ways to arrange A, B, C, D, E, this makes it **5! x 5!**
> in total of ways to select a committee.

**Second answer:**

> P can be assigned to 5 people
>
> V can be assigned to 4 people
>
> X can be assigned to 3 people
>
> V can be assigned to the last 2 people
>
> Total: **5x4x3** ways to select a committee.

So is any of those answers correct? If yes then which one? And more important, WHY? Please explain like I'm 5, use logic, not formula or anything complicated. I've been struggling to understand combinatorics for a while now; it gets worse and worse but I can't give up.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Your second answer is correct, as is the reasoning used to reach it. Alternatively, you could start with the Treasurers: there are $\binom52$ ways to choose them. After that there are $3$ ways to choose the President and $2$ ways to choose the Vice President. Thus, there are

$$\binom52\cdot3\cdot2=10\cdot3\cdot2=60$$

different ways to populate the committee.

Your first answer is incorrect because it ignores the fact that the two Treasurer positions are indistinguishable. Suppose that $A$ chooses to be a Treasurer: then $A$ was really choosing from only $4$ different positions, not $5$. If $A$ chooses to be a Treasurer, then it’s true that $B$ is choosing from $4$ different positions, but if $A$ chooses to be President or Vice President, $B$ is choosing from only $3$ different positions, not $4$. That analysis quickly gets a bit ugly as you consider the various cases.

Answer (score 1):

"John is to select a committee of 4 individuals from among a group of 5 candi­dates. The committee will have a President, a Vice President, and two Trea­surers. How many different committees can John select from the 5 candidates?"

First, because, "President" and "Vice President" are specifically mentioned, we must consider the same four people, but different President and Vice President as different committees.

John can first select a President.  There are 5 people to choose from so there are 5 ways to do that.  Then he must choose a Vice President.  There are 4 people left to choose from so there are 4 ways to do that.

There are 5(4)= 20 ways to choose the President and Vice President.  There are now 3 people left from which to choose there are two treasurers.  There are two ways to calculate this.

We could say, as above, that there are 3 people to choose the first treasurer and then 2 ways to choose the next.  But there is no distinction between the two positions so no "first" and no "next".  Choosing "A" and then "B", "AB", is the same as choosing "B" and then "A", BA.  We need to divide by two: 3(2)/2= 3.

Or we could say that choosing two out of three to be treasures is the same as choosint one out of those three to NOT be treasurer.  There are 3 ways to do that.

So there are 5(4)(3)= 60 ways to choose such a committee.